# Erase last members of line from text file

Tags: c, char

I have a text file as `data.txt` and I want to delete the last members of each line:

Here's the text file:

```
2031,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,54,0,
2027,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,209,0,
2029,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,65,0,
2036,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,165,0,
```

I would like to delete so it becomes:

```
2031,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,
2027,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,
2029,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,
2036,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,
```

I'm working in **C** but as the numbers can have two or three digits, I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Does it have to be C?  There are a lot of scripting languages that would be able to do this in about 3.14 lines of code.

Comment: I know, but I want to integrate it with a bigger program in c I already have.

Comment: That makes sense.  The real world has a habit of getting in the way and preventing us from using the simple solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of uses of `strrchr()` can do the job:

```
#include <string.h>

void zap_last_field(char *line)
{
    char *last_comma = strrchr(line, ',');
    if (last_comma != 0)
    {
        *last_comma = '\0';
        last_comma = strrchr(line, ',');
        if (last_comma != 0)
            *(last_comma + 1) = '\0';
    }
}
```

Compiled code that seems to work.  Note that given a string containing a single comma, it will zap that comma.  If you don't want that to happen, then you have to work a little harder.

#### Test code for `zap_last_field()`

```
#include <string.h>

extern void zap_last_field(char *line);

void zap_last_field(char *line)
{
    char *last_comma = strrchr(line, ',');
    if (last_comma != 0)
    {
        *last_comma = '\0';
        last_comma = strrchr(line, ',');
        if (last_comma != 0)
            *(last_comma + 1) = '\0';
    }
}

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *line = malloc(4096);
    if (line != 0)
    {

        while (fgets(line, 4096, stdin) != 0)
        {
            printf("Line: %s", line);
            zap_last_field(line);
            printf("Zap1: %s\n", line);
        }
        free(line);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

This has been vetted with `valgrind` and is OK on both the original data file and the mangled data file listed below.  The dynamic memory allocation is there to give `valgrind` the maximum chance of spotting any problems.

I strongly suspect that the core dump reported in a comment happens because the alternative test code tried to pass a literal string to the function, which won't work because literal strings are not generally modifiable and this code modifies the string in situ.

#### Test code for `zap_last_n_fields()`

If you want to zap the last couple of fields (a controlled number of fields), then you'll probably want to pass in a count of the number of fields to be zapped and add a loop.  Note that this code uses a VLA so it requires a C99 compiler.

```
#include <string.h>

extern void zap_last_n_fields(char *line, size_t nfields);

void zap_last_n_fields(char *line, size_t nfields)
{
    char *zapped[nfields+1];

    for (size_t i = 0; i <= nfields; i++)
    {
        char *last_comma = strrchr(line, ',');
        if (last_comma != 0)
        {
            zapped[i] = last_comma;
            *last_comma = '\0';
        }
        else
        {
            /* Undo the damage wrought above */
            for (size_t j = 0; j < i; j++)
                *zapped[j] = ',';
            return;
        }
    }
    zapped[nfields][0] = ','; 
    zapped[nfields][1] = '\0';
}

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char line1[4096];

    while (fgets(line1, sizeof(line1), stdin) != 0)
    {
        printf("Line: %s", line1);
        char line2[4096];
        for (size_t i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            strcpy(line2, line1);
            zap_last_n_fields(line2, i);
            printf("Zap%zd: %s\n", i, line2);
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Example run — using your `data.txt` as input:

```
Line: 2031,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,54,0,
Zap1: 2031,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,54,
Zap2: 2031,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,
Zap3: 2031,2,0,0,0,0,0,
Line: 2027,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,209,0,
Zap1: 2027,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,209,
Zap2: 2027,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,
Zap3: 2027,2,0,0,0,0,0,
Line: 2029,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,65,0,
Zap1: 2029,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,65,
Zap2: 2029,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,
Zap3: 2029,2,0,0,0,0,0,
Line: 2036,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,165,0,
Zap1: 2036,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,165,
Zap2: 2036,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,
Zap3: 2036,2,0,0,0,0,0,
```

It also correctly handles a file such as:

```
2031,0,0,
2031,0,
2031,
2031
,
```

Comment: It gives me 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)'

Comment: I expect that's because you passed it a string literal in your test code...see update showing test code for `zap_last_field()`.